# Limit of monotone increasing sequence is supremum

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a real sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which is monotone increasing, i.e. $x_n \leq x_{n + 1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I think it is true that $$\sup\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$$ Has anyone a hint for me how I could prove this?

Comment: What is the definition of the supremum of a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

By the definition of supremum, the quantity $(\sup_{m \geq 1} x_m) - \epsilon$ is **not** an upper bound, so there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $x_N > (\sup_{m \geq 1} x_m) - \epsilon$.

For any $n > N$, $$(\sup_{m \geq 1} x_m) \geq x_n \geq  x_N > (\sup_{ m \geq 1} x_m) - \epsilon.$$

By the $\epsilon-N$ definition, it follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = (\sup_{m \geq 1} x_m)$, as desired.