# How to show $2$ is the supremum of sequence defined by $a_{1}=1,a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_{n}}$ without using its convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> How to show $2$ is the supremum of sequence defined by $a_{1}=1,a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_{n}}$?

Motivation to question is showing that this sequence converges to its supremum $2$, it's what remained to show, since it is increasing and bounded by mathematical induction.

Comment: You showed it converges. Denote its limit by $a$. Can you see that $a=\sqrt{2a}$?

Comment: @Gary Yes, by monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Gary: But is there a way to show $2$ is the supremum without using monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: Monoton convergence theorem? No, it is much simpler. Take the limit on both sides of the defining recurrence.

Comment: @Gary But we conclude it converges, because it is increasing and bounded?
Is it simpler?(I mean this what allowed us to take limit on both sides of the recurrence)

Comment: Related: [Limit of monotone increasing sequence is supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977204/limit-of-monotone-increasing-sequence-is-supremum).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the supremum of a set of nested square roots is 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732264/prove-that-the-supremum-of-a-set-of-nested-square-roots-is-2) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D%5Csqrt%7B2a_%7Bn%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a_%7B1%7D%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asupremum&p=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a kind of complicated way that does not use convergence of $a_n$ in any way. First, the outline:

- Show that $a_n<2$ by induction, so $\sup a_n\leq2$.
- Show that if $\sup a_n<2$, then there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_N>\sup a_n$, resulting in a contradiction.

**$\sup a_n\leq2$:**

$a_1<2$ is true, and if $a_n<2$, then $a_{n+1}^2=2a_n<2\cdot2=4$, and since $\sqrt{}$ is monotone increasing, $a_{n+1}<2$.

**$\sup a_n=2$:**

Assume $\sup a_n<2$. First we note that we can make $a_n$ be arbitrarily close to $\sup a_n$ if we choose $n$ suitably. We can express this the following way: If $0<r<1$, then there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{a_N}{\sup a_n}>r$. That is, we can get the ratio of $a_N$ and $\sup a_n$ as close to $1$ as we like. You may want to prove this yourself.

Given this, we can see that if $a_N>r\sup a_n$, then

$$a_{N+1}=\sqrt{2a_N}>\sqrt{2r\sup a_n}=\sqrt r\sqrt{2\sup a_n}.$$

Choose $r$ such that $1>r>\frac{\sup a_n}{\sqrt{2\sup a_n}}$ (convince yourself that this is possible). Since $\sqrt r>r$ we get

$$\begin{align}a_{N+1}&>\sqrt r\sqrt{2\sup a_n}\\
&>r\sqrt{2\sup a_n}\\
&>\frac{\sup a_n}{\sqrt{2\sup a_n}}\sqrt{2\sup a_n}\\
&=\sup a_n
\end{align}$$

Here's our contradiction, so $\sup a_n$ can't be smaller than $2$, but in the first step we also showed that it can't be larger, so it must be exactly $2$.

Comment: Many thanks to you, your answer is highly cool. With high concentration, all parts of your answer  are clear and understandable.

Answer (score 4):

Note that :

$$\begin{align}&a_1=2^0\\
&a_2=\sqrt {2 \cdot 1}=2^{\frac 12}\\
&a_3=\sqrt {2\cdot \sqrt {2}}=2^{\frac 12+\frac 14}\\
&a_4=\sqrt{2\cdot\sqrt {2\cdot \sqrt {2}}}=2^{\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18}\\
&\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\cdots\cdots\cdots\end{align}$$

$\rm {Closed-form \thinspace \thinspace formula :}$

By induction, we can also derive the *closed-form* formula :

$$
\begin{align}a_1=1,a_n&=2^{\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}},\thinspace n≥2\end{align}
$$

Then, using the [geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) formula we have :

$$a_n=2^{1-2^{1-n}},\thinspace n≥1$$

This implies that :

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{1-2^{1-n}}=2\end{align}$$

---

Or using the *infinite geometric series* formula, you have :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=2^{\frac {\frac 12}{1-\frac 12}}=2\thinspace.\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your highly cool solution.

Comment: Can we show $2$ is the supremum without knowing it is convergent?

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar I didn't take calculus courses...So I don't want to mislead you.  Experts who see your question here will surely answer you.  Be sure.

Comment: My question is in real analysis not calculus, anyway thank you for your good answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline of Proof:**
You can show by induction on $n \ge 1$ that $a_n < 2$ and the sequence is strictly increasing by induction as well. Then it converges to $L$ and $L = \sqrt{2L} \implies L = 2$. Since the sequence is increasing and converges to $L = 2$ then this value is also the supremum.

Comment: Can we show $2$ is the supremum without knowing it is convergent?And thank you for your good answer.

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar Does it help that $$
a_n  = 2^{\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{2^k }}} }  = 2^{1 - 2^{1 - n} } \,?
$$ Note that the power of two is always less than $1$ but can get arbitrarily close to $1$. Hence, the sumpremum must be $2^1 =2$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A closed form formula can be obtained by applying $\log_2$ to each side and solving the resulting linear recurrence

$$
L_{n+1}=\frac 12(1+L_n),\ \ \ L_1 = 0
$$

which gives $L_n = 1-2^{1-k}$ hence $a_n = 2^{1-2^{1-k}}$

Comment: Thank you for your good answer.